# Django: Use Proxy Models and lost history

Tags: django, orm, django-admin

i implement two proxy models from a main model to use them in different ModelAdmins with different get_queryset´s. ALl is running fine. But i lost the change history of the object if it switches between the main model to the proxy model. Is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Django manage logs in **django_admin_log** table, where data store **content_type** wise. When you create a proxy model then a new content_type is created.

```
django_content_type:

+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| app_label | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

django_admin_log:

+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| action_time     | datetime(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| object_id       | longtext          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| object_repr     | varchar(200)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| action_flag     | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| change_message  | longtext          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content_type_id | int               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int               | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In Django **ModelAdmin** class, **history_view**() method is written where get history data on the basis of **content_type**. The below query is used for getting history data.

```
LogEntry.objects.filter(
    object_id=unquote(object_id),
    content_type=get_content_type_for_model(model),
)
.select_related()
.order_by("action_time")
```

If you combined main model and proxy model history data then you can use IN query for field content_type.